# How to get an average of a hasMany instance property in grails domain classes?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two classes in Grails application ,**Employee** has hasMany(one To Many relations) for another class called **Vote**

```
class Employee {
   String employeeName   
   static hasMany = [votes:Vote]
}
```

and vote class has voteRank integer property, and all employees vote on scale of 1-10 and every employee contains list of these votes given by other employees

```
class Vote {
   Integer voteRank
   static belongsTo =[employee:Employee]
}
```

How do I get the avg of all votes given per employee. This can be solved in SQL by using group by clause. But i am looking for grails domain mapping and gorm oriented answer for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a simple method on the Employee domain class.

```
class Employee {
    String employeeName
    static hasMany = [votes: Vote]

    def sumVotes() {
        votes.voteRank.sum() / votes.size()
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on how you want to handle it if `voteRank` is nullable. You could count it as 0 and use `votes.voteRank.sum { it ? it : 0 }`.

Comment: IMHO: this solution will give bad results as size() will give back the the values count including null values. perhaps filtering out them is a good option:
    votes.findAll{it.voteRank!=null}.with{it.voteRank.sum() / it.size()}

Answer (score 4):

This HQL query will work:

```
def averages = Employee.executeQuery(
    'select e, avg(vote.voteRank) ' +
    'from Employee e join e.votes vote ' +
    'group by e')
```

This will return a `List` of `Object[]` arrays where the first element is the `Employee` and the second is the average. If you don't want to return the whole `Employee` instances you can select one or more properties:

```
def averages = Employee.executeQuery(
    'select e.employeeName, avg(vote.voteRank) ' +
    'from Employee e join e.votes vote ' +
    'group by e')
```